# FindViewById Null When Used In Child Class

Tags: android, class

I'm using a child class which extends from main to setup some buttons. I am able to change variables created in main, such as TotalMoney from within child.

The problem is findViewById is giving a nullpointer exception. The code within buildthem() works fine when used in the main class.

I am using setContentView(R.layout.main); from within OnCreate in main. The Child class is instantiated and called from OnResume in main class.

Do I need to setContentView in the child aswell, or pass the content view from the main class somehow?

```
package com.chewyapps.markettrader;

         class child extends main {

     void buildthem(){

         TotalMoney = TotalMoney + 9999;


          Button MenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Menu);
           //etc

     }
}
```

I can't findViewById in Oncreate because the full code will use

```
         for(i=0; i<buttonIDs.length; i++) {                
                    Button b = (Button) findViewById(buttonIDs[i]);
//do other stuff    
    }
```

The for loop is needed for other things relating to each button. If I can get the basic example working though I assume the full code will work.

It hadn't occured to me before to mention this, but the child class is in a seperate file called child.java, from my main.java file in onResume I use:

```
child childObject = new child ();
     childObject.buildthem();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put this line:

```
Button MenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Menu);
```

in `onCreate()`, then you can either pass `MenuButton` into `buildthem()` as a parameter or reference it directly, depending on your design.

Please note that Java convention is to have variable names start with a lowercase letter, so `menuButton` not `MenuButton`.

**EDIT**
Then why not create an array of `Button`s in `onCreate()` that you can later iterate through?

```
Button myButtons[] = new Button[buttonIDs.length];
for(int i=0; i<buttonIDs.length; i++) {                
    myButtons[i] = (Button) findViewById(buttonIDs[i]);
}
```

Then just iterate over the `myButtons` array in your child class.

Comment: Ok thanks, I may do that. I just assumed it would be fairly easy to move the existing code into a different class

Comment: @Tom humphries - would it be possible for you to post your actual code?  Something is amiss here that is hard to decipher from the code you posted.  Calling findViewById in a child class of your Activity should work properly.  It is acting like you are calling findViewById when the view is not inflated or on the wrong context.  I suspect your note about this happening in onResume may be key.

Comment: @slund Thanks, what what I've read I think it must be something like that. Not sure what of the code to post which is most relevant. I've edited the original post which may clarify what I'm doing...

Comment: @Tom humphries if `child` extends `main`and `main` extends `Activity` then you **cannot** do this.  Do not ever instantiate a class that extends `Activity`.

Comment: @Tom humphries if all you are doing is setting up some buttons, I'm not sure why you need to extend your `Activity`.  Just create a `static` method in a `Util` class and pass the array of buttons in, along with any other objects you need in order to perform the setup.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Button MenuButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Menu);
```

or

```
Button MenuButton = (Button) Child.this.findViewById(R.id.Menu);
```

Comment: hmm these don't seem to make any difference :(

Comment: Meant:    Button MenuButton = (Button) Parent.this.findViewById(R.id.Menu);

Comment: If I try that eclipse shows "No enclosing instance of the type main is accessible in scope"